# C++ Check if one of multple values lower than int

Tags: c++, if-statement

I`m currently trying something with C++ and want to make the code a bit cleaner.

My if-statement is

```
if(value1 < 1 || value2 < 1)
```

My question is if there is a way to make this shorter like

```
if(value1 or value2 < 1)
```

Do I already have the shortest solution or is there a better way to make it?

Thanks in advance 
Tim

Comment: There's no such short cut in c++.

Comment: What's cleaner than a binary yes/no answer... You think too much like a human...

Comment: Why does it need to be shorter? Write code so that it is *clear*. With C++, you're ultimately running the code through an optimizing compiler, so there is no possible speed improvement to be had for "compressing" (obfuscating) the code. So while yes, this can be done with bitwise tricks, it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I thought that it is better if all is shorter, but it's right. If it is good to read for me it should be the best solution.